# GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES EXCEPTION: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate Google Play Games into my app. It is currently working in debug mode. However, it does not seem to work in release mode. I am getting errors. I tried clean and rebuild.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

And then this one:

> GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES EXCEPTION: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil

Followed by this one:

> There is a problem with the Google Play Services library, which is
>   required for Android Advertising ID support. The Google Play Services
>   library should be integrated in any app shipping in the Play Store
>   that uses analytics or advertising.

What could be wrong? I tried experimenting with Gradle, but no luck yet.

If I disable Proguard, it works! This seems to be a known issue, but not resolved yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have minifyEnabled true in your build.gradle?

Comment: which version of google play services are you using?

Comment: @g2o Yes, and if I disable it, it works! 8.3.0. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593632/proguard-obfuscation-issues-after-adding-new-google-sign-in-to-android-applicati

Comment: if you wish to use minify, in my experience it doesn't work well with play services 8 (as you have discovered) but it does seem to work with 7.6.?

Comment: If something work on debug and not in release, for me 80% of the problem is with ofuscation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in my Gradle I was using

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Now I am using

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

add below code in your `proguard-rule.pro` and try to regenerate APK

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.**{ *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```